# Pandas: "if" block does not get executed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

When I execute below code, it only executes "else" clause even when "if" condition is satisfied.
    For example

```
 Date   05/01/2006
 Open   5521.86
 Low    5502.25 
 Close.shift(1) 5523.620117
```

It satisfies "if" block condition (i.e.)

```
 DAX_Logic < 1 *(value is 0.99968132240039786)*
```

However the "if" block never gets executed. Please assist

```
DAX=pd.io.data.DataReader("^GDAXI","yahoo",start,end)
DAX_Logic= DAX['Open'].fillna(1) / DAX['Close'].shift(1).fillna(1)
DAX_Logic_1=  DAX['Low'].fillna(1) / DAX['Open'].fillna(1) 
if DAX_Logic.any() < 1:
    Daily_Return = 100*(DAX['Low']-DAX['Open'])
else:
    Daily_Return = (-100)*(DAX['Close']-DAX['Open'])
```

I tried using the following piece of code and the below piece only executes "If" block and never "else" block... Bit confused what I am doing wrong in above and below code.(They produce completely opposite results)

```
DAX=pd.io.data.DataReader("^GDAXI","yahoo",start,end)
DAX_Logic= DAX['Open'].fillna(1) / DAX['Close'].shift(1).fillna(1)
DAX_Logic_1=  DAX['Low'].fillna(1) / DAX['Open'].fillna(1) 
for i in DAX_Logic.index[:]:
    if (DAX_Logic[i] < 1):
        Daily_Return = 100*(DAX['Low']-DAX['Open'])
    else:
        Daily_Return = (-100)*(DAX['Close']-DAX['Open'])
```

Comment: You say `DAX_Logic < 1 *(value is 0.99968132240039786)*`, but the if statement reads `if DAX_Logic.any() < 1:`, maybe DAX_Logic.any() returns a different value than DAX_Logic.

Comment: Those boolean expression only works inside `DAX[DAX['Low'] < 1]` or with .ix or similar, but not normal if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are running general purpose python with `for` and `if` in place of vectorized pandas operations such as conditionally creating columns (i.e., series) by logical indexing with another series.

Consider first adding *DAX_Logic* and *DAX_Logic_1* as new columns in *DAX* dataframe inline with other rows, allowing you to use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to create *Daily_Return* column:

```
DAX = pd.io.data.DataReader("^GDAXI","yahoo",start,end)
# NEW COLUMNS (NOT SEPARATE SERIES)
DAX['DAX_Logic'] = DAX['Open'].fillna(1) / DAX['Close'].shift(1).fillna(1)
DAX['DAX_Logic_1'] = DAX['Low'].fillna(1) / DAX['Open'].fillna(1)

# DAILY RETURN
DAX.loc[DAX['DAX_Logic'] > 1, 'Daily_Return'] = 100*(DAX['Low']-DAX['Open'])
DAX.loc[DAX['DAX_Logic'] <= 1, 'Daily_Return'] = (-100)*(DAX['Close']-DAX['Open'])
```

Alternatively, use numpy's [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for vectorized if/else calculations:

```
import numpy as np

DAX['Daily_Return'] = np.where(DAX['DAX_Logic'] > 1, 100*(DAX['Low']-DAX['Open']), (-100)*(DAX['Close']-DAX['Open']))
```

And if you want *Daily_Return* to standalone outside of a dataframe column, simply assign it since every column in a pandas dataframe is a pandas series:

```
Daily_Return = DAX['Daily_Return']
```

Comment: Thank you @Parfait. This is great solution and perfect.